# Connect Mongodb with unity error with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System; 
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;  
using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;  
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;  
public class DBHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    void Start () {
        /*
     * Establish connection
     */
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer(); 
        var database = server.GetDatabase("unity");
        var shopcollections= database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("vrshop");
        Debug.Log ("Connected!!0.0");
        //print all collections
        foreach (var document in shopcollections.FindAll()) {
            Debug.Log ("Get all info: \n" + document);
        }
    }
}
```

These code used to work, and it can connect to mongodb successfully, however, today, when I try to connect it, it comes out with an error:

```
MongoConnectionException: Unable to resolve host name 'localhost'.
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerAddress.ToIPEndPoint (AddressFamily addressFamily)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.GetIPEndPoint ()
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open ()
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.GetNetworkStream ()
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage (MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBuffer buffer, Int32 requestId)
Rethrow as MongoConnectionException: Unable to connect to server localhost:27017: Unable to resolve host name 'localhost'..
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect (TimeSpan timeout, MongoDB.Driver.ReadPreference readPreference)
MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.ChooseServerInstance (MongoDB.Driver.ReadPreference readPreference)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.AcquireConnection (MongoDB.Driver.ReadPreference readPreference)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1+MongoCursorConnectionProvider[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument].AcquireConnection ()
MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument].GetFirstBatch (IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument].Execute (IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument].GetEnumerator ()
DBHandler.Start () (at Assets/DBHandler.cs:24)
```

I am sure that I use the same mongodb....What's wrong with it ?

Comment: First of all check if anything on your computer is accessible as 'localhost'. Try pinging it, if you have webserver running try to access it in browser as http://localhost/ etc. Check Firewall settings if you have one running. Check 'hosts' file for any weird records.

Comment: Yes, I can access localhost: 27017 from my Robomongo...I think that means I can access to it....However,I don't know why for unity?..

Comment: If you are running Firewall there might be rule based on the application. So your unity application might not have proper setting for the access to 27017 on localhost. If your Unity application got updated recently, it might require Firewall rule to be updated as well.

Comment: I am using mac, but how to check my setting of Firewall in Unity...

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642 Try this one. I'm not Mac user myself, so probably can not help you much with that :/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check that out.

Comment: @GSazheniuk I have closed the firewallQAQ...Still doesn't wok..

Comment: Well, all I can do is to suggest you to use IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: change "mongodb://localhost:27017" to "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" doe snot work..

Comment: Did you add your mongodb drivers with Nuget or downloaded DLLs ans added them to Unity? I'm trying to use GridFS driver but I cet errors poping because my DLLs can't ne loaded. Which drivers version did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed that... Just as the comment said that change mongodb://localhost:27017 to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 works..